# Finding basis for V and W

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $$T\colon V\to W$$
be a linear transformation defined by the matrix A where
$$A=
\left[
        \begin{matrix}
        -1 & 2 & 3 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & -1 & -2 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
\right]
$$

I have to find basis for $V = R^3$ and $W = R^4$ to make the matrix of T as simple as possible.

How would I go about doing this? I've never done something like this before and I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: What do you mean "find basis given the matrix" ? Their bases should not depend on the transformation.

Comment: Accidentally left something out so I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: How about you take the columns of the matrix, and add one vector to complete that to a basis of $\Bbb{R}^4$? Then the matrix will look like the 3-by-3 identity matrix with a row of zeros underneath it.